# prototype returning [function] instead of Array

Tags: javascript, prototype

I am creating a prototype function for Number. As soon as I call it i get [Function] returned or the body of my function. I wonder what I did wrong. Help is appreciated.

```
Number.prototype.splitDigits = function(){
        var str = this.toString;
        var arrayDigits = [];
        var length = str.length;
        for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
            arrayDigits.push(Number(str.charAt(i)));
        }
        return arrayDigits;
    };
```

I am calling the function like this:

```
var num = 2000;
var array = num.splitDigits;
```

What I am getting in return is:

```
[Function]
```

or

```
a0 function (){
    var str = this.toString;
    var arrayDigits = [];
    var length = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
        arrayDigits.push(Number(str.charAt(i)));
    }
    return arrayDigits;
}
```

Comment: You need to call the function `var array = num.splitDigits()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two faults in your code.

1. this.toString -> this.toString()
2. splitDigits -> splitDigits()

**After fix**

```
Number.prototype.splitDigits = function(){
    var str = this.toString();
    var arrayDigits = [];
    var length = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
        arrayDigits.push(Number(str.charAt(i)));
    }
    return arrayDigits;
};
```

**Run**

```
> var num = 2000;
> var array = num.splitDigits();
> array
[2, 0, 0, 0]
```

Comment: Thats what did the trick. I always get pretty confused where to actually add the brackets. For example ".length" does not need the brackets, whereas ".toString" does need it.

Comment: You can read the source code of each function. If the return is function(callback), you should use brackets. If the return is direct value, you should not use brackets. If you want to know more about this, searching "currying" will help you a lot.

Comment: Thank you sir, you helped me a lot. I will do the research and get my learning curve going. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You are not calling the function. If you don't want to call it explicitly, you can use a getter:

```js
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'splitDigits', {
  configurable: true,
  get: function() {
    var str = this.toString();
    var arrayDigits = [];
    var length = str.length;
    for (var i = 0; i<length; i++){
      arrayDigits.push(Number(str.charAt(i)));
    }
    return arrayDigits;
  }
});
var num = 2000;
console.log(num.splitDigits);
```

Be aware your code won't work with numbers like `1e100`

Answer (score 0):

You don't call the function. Only, you assing the funtion to the array.

Tray the following code to call function.

```
var num = 2000;
var array = num.splitDigits();
```

Answer (score 0):

> You need to *call* the function

Without the braces, you just access the property you defined for Number. And that is a function.